# Best method to execute method before layout is made

Tags: android

I've a method `createLayout();` (simple fragment) . Before I create layout I want to remove one fragment off the stack using `popBackStackImmediate();`. Problem is, that `popBackStackImmediate();` executes a lot slower than `createLayout();` which leaves me to creating layout alot faster than I need to. What are the best possible solution here? I would like to build layout only when `popBackStackImmediate();` is finished. What are the best solutions for this case?

Comment: ViewTreeObserver might help you https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html

Comment: have you tried using `executePendingTransactions();` before `createLayout();` ?

Comment: @Belzebub I did. Same result. :(